# Allow Visual Studio for Mac permission to use the Desktop?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

When opening a Visuals Studio solution on a Mac I got a popup asking me to give VS permission to use the Desktop. I accidentally clicked don't allow and now can't load the solution.

I tried looking under preferences but couldn't find how to allow it. I also tried closing and reopening the solution, but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
System Preferences --> Security & Privacy --> Privacy tab --> Files & Folders
-> Grant VS permisions
```

OR... just move your solution to another folder